# PoE from 2960 without Layer 1 Connection

Tags: cisco, power-over-ethernet

I'm attempting to use a Cisco 2960-X (LPS-L) to provide power for a some Nexus 7 tablets (via a TP-LINK PoE Splitter).

The issue is that without some actual device connected to the LAN port of the PoE splitter, the 2960 won't keep the port up and power flowing (it just keeps cycling it on and off).  We've used this setup successfully with RaspberryPi's before (where they draw both power and LAN from the switch), so we know that these switches will work with these particular PoE splitters if something is connected to the LAN side too.

We've already tried using a loopback plug (pinning 1->3 and 2->6) to trick the switch but that doesn't work.

So: how can we trick the 2960 into thinking there is something connected on the other end and keeping the link and power flowing?  Ideally it needs to be as small and cheap as possible (hence the attempt with the loopback plug) so that it just sits as part of the PoE splitter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a cheap USB-to-Ethernet dongle attached to the Nexus (to power the dongle) and to the Ethernet port. My guess is the PHY in the dongle will make the switch happy and you shouldn't need to load the drivers for the dongle on the Nexus to get it to power the dongle. If this works you can probably get some very exceedingly cheap USB 1.0 to Ethernet dongles to fit the bill.